Can't connect to a specific Wi-Fi with error : unsupported get ioctl on awdl0
I'm trying to connect to a mixed 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz Wi-Fi. When trying to connect with the right password, my Mac is asking me to type the password again. By checking the logs, I was able to find what was the error:
_Apple80211AWDLCompatibilityInternal: unsupported get ioctl on awdl0 for APPLE80211_IOC_CURRENT_NETWORK[103]

The first time it happened was random, I was on the internet and connected to the same Wi-Fi and then suddenly I didn't have access to the internet and my Mac was asking me to type my password.
By running ifconfig, I was able to see that, both, awdl0 and llw0 were inactive (which lead to Airdrop and Airplay being unusable). I was able to activate awdl0 back but not llw0.
Here are the things that I have tried so far:

Forget Wi-Fi
Removing the following files:
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist 
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist 
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist 
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist


Reset NVRAM/PRAM
sudo ifconfig llw0 up (not working, llw0 still inactive)
Restart in safe mode
Manually adding the Wi-Fi
Reinstall macOS
Try another session

None of them worked. I also tried providing an IP address manually throughout my router's interface but it didn't work as well. Separating 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz worked but only for the 2.4 GHz bandwidth. 5 GHz on my MacBook works well on a different Wi-Fi.
I have a 13 inch MacBook Pro M1 Sonoma 14.5 (up to date)
Any ideas? I want to avoid a factory reset.

Turned out my wifi's repeater was the issue, I couldn't find the reason to why it occurred but I simply reset my repeater and everything was fine. It's unfortunate that I don't have the exact reason to why it happened. I was able to detect the problem by creating a guest network which doesn't use any repeater and my MacBook could connect to my main router perfectly.

Can you elaborate to help future travelers?
